# Best way to partition Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with windows 7 on 1 Terra HD. (with priority for Ubuntu)

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I have a new laptop without OS.
I want to install Windows 7 (and give it a small space) just in case I need it for a specific software or game.
In parallel I'm a Ubuntu user so I want to give it the biggest space on the hard disk.

what is the perfect scenario to do that?
do I need to create C:/ and D:/ on windows?
if I have 8 GB of Ram how much the SWAP of Ubuntu should be?
do I create the /home during installation of Ubuntu?

Help.

Comment: this is an opinion base question you should avoid those kind of question on most stackexchange

Comment: well in this case you ask for something everybody can give you a different answer and depending on your use and skills the answer can be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various possibilities. Here are some scenarios.

## Simple

Partition 1: Ubuntu (remaining space)
Partition 2: Swap (16GB)
Partition 3: Windows (100GB)

## With common partition for Data

Partition 1: Ubuntu (200GB)
Partition 2: Swap (16GB)
Partition 3: Windows (100GB)
Partition 4: Data (NTFS, remaining space)

## With separate home partition

Partition 1: Ubuntu (200GB)
Partition 2: Swap (16GB)
Partition 3: Windows (100GB)
Partition 4: Home (ext4, mount point /home, remaining space)

Comment: What about separating more partitions (like /var, /usr, etc.)?